# Create a unique id from each id in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries with the key named `id`, however, some of these are duplicates. This is a sample of my dataset, my actual dicts have multiple keys but I'm filtering my `id`. Essentially, I do not want to remove the ids, instead I want to create a new id value by incrementing a number onto it to create a new number. However, this number must not be existing in the current list of ids. However, I find that one but all are transformed.

For example:

```
import copy
ids = [{'id': 44},{'id': 49},{'id': 48},{'id': 53},{'id': 46},{'id': 51},{'id': 45},{'id': 50},{'id': 47},{'id': 52},{'id': 5091},{'id': 5060},{'id': 5002},{'id': 5071},{'id': 5011},{'id': 5027},{'id': 26},{'id': 29},{'id': 5034},{'id': 5086},{'id': 5063},{'id': 5022},{'id': 5014},{'id': 74},{'id': 5061},{'id': 4},{'id': 5013},{'id': 5076},{'id': 5055},{'id': 5006},{'id': 5051},{'id': 5032},{'id': 5008},{'id': 14},{'id': 35},{'id': 5},{'id': 7},{'id': 64},{'id': 5049},{'id': 5021},{'id': 5059},{'id': 5029},{'id': 6},{'id': 30},{'id': 23},{'id': 31},{'id': 5017},{'id': 8},{'id': 17},{'id': 24},{'id': 5007},{'id': 5033},{'id': 5065},{'id': 5020},{'id': 5085},{'id': 5025},{'id': 5068},{'id': 5041},{'id': 5048},{'id': 5056},{'id': 5080},{'id': 5070},{'id': 5072},{'id': 5077},{'id': 5073},{'id': 5067},{'id': 5088},{'id': 5010},{'id': 5040},{'id': 5075},{'id': 5035},{'id': 5043},{'id': 5012},{'id': 5052},{'id': 5081},{'id': 5004},{'id': 57},{'id': 56},{'id': 63},{'id': 62},{'id': 55},{'id': 54},{'id': 22},{'id': 59},{'id': 58},{'id': 61},{'id': 60},{'id': 21},{'id': 5046},{'id': 5024},{'id': 5036},{'id': 5058},{'id': 5053},{'id': 5044},{'id': 38},{'id': 36},{'id': 5050},{'id': 5047},{'id': 5079},{'id': 5062},{'id': 37},{'id': 13},{'id': 3},{'id': 27},{'id': 5078},{'id': 5009},{'id': 5069},{'id': 5092},{'id': 5090},{'id': 66},{'id': 81},{'id': 82},{'id': 70},{'id': 67},{'id': 75},{'id': 78},{'id': 76},{'id': 5001},{'id': 68},{'id': 69},{'id': 79},{'id': 65},{'id': 71},{'id': 77},{'id': 73},{'id': 72},{'id': 5031},{'id': 5083},{'id': 5037},{'id': 5003},{'id': 15},{'id': 16},{'id': 25},{'id': 32},{'id': 5023},{'id': 2},{'id': 5038},{'id': 5030},{'id': 5019},{'id': 5087},{'id': 5089},{'id': 5082},{'id': 5028},{'id': 5054},{'id': 5074},{'id': 5018},{'id': 5015},{'id': 5064},{'id': 5045},{'id': 5057},{'id': 5084},{'id': 5026},{'id': 5016},{'id': 12},{'id': 11},{'id': 10},{'id': 5066},{'id': 5042},{'id': 5005},{'id': 28},{'id': 80},{'id': 17131},{'id': 6646},{'id': 6440},{'id': 11253},{'id': 6254},{'id': 6240},{'id': 10547},{'id': 10495},{'id': 8179},{'id': 8139},{'id': 10726},{'id': 17285},{'id': 6566},{'id': 10760},{'id': 16521},{'id': 10732},{'id': 17627},{'id': 10179},{'id': 17433},{'id': 17437},{'id': 17435},{'id': 6554},{'id': 6560},{'id': 6562},{'id': 6664},{'id': 12507},{'id': 12509},{'id': 11275},{'id': 6606},{'id': 17287},{'id': 17289},{'id': 12511},{'id': 12221},{'id': 8705},{'id': 17129},{'id': 8691},{'id': 11078},{'id': 11697},{'id': 6604},{'id': 6590},{'id': 17413},{'id': 17217},{'id': 11076},{'id': 10724},{'id': 11487},{'id': 5188},{'id': 6049},{'id': 6556},{'id': 6558},{'id': 6700},{'id': 6548},{'id': 5437},{'id': 4},{'id': 6244},{'id': 5061},{'id': 10085},{'id': 12707},{'id': 35},{'id': 64},{'id': 18003},{'id': 6442},{'id': 6710},{'id': 12709},{'id': 11255},{'id': 11273},{'id': 17279},{'id': 17277},{'id': 17975},{'id': 16981},{'id': 6676},{'id': 6550},{'id': 6842},{'id': 37},{'id': 11054},{'id': 5444},{'id': 6426},{'id': 70},{'id': 67},{'id': 75},{'id': 6234},{'id': 8880},{'id': 8899},{'id': 13835},{'id': 14759},{'id': 7112},{'id': 5017},{'id': 6236},{'id': 9923},{'id': 16817},{'id': 5228},{'id': 5029}]
aID = copy.deepcopy(ids)
uniques = set([ x.get('id') for x in ids ])
listOf = [ x.get('id') for x in ids ]
G = True
d= 0
for items in aID:
    if items.get('id') in uniques and listOf.count(items.get('id')) > 1:
        G = True
        while(G):
            d += 1
            if(items.get('id') + d not in uniques):
                items.update({'id': items.get('id')+ d})
                G = False
            else:
                continue
```

When I check for any duplicate ids I get a few:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Where did I go wrong in my loop?

I have attempted the following, which works fine on the data above but may produce duplicates on my actual dataset:

```
aID = copy.deepcopy(ids)
uniques = set()

for item in aID:
    d = 0
    while item['id'] + d in uniques:
        d += 1
    item['id'] += d
    uniques.add(item['id'])
    while items.get('id') + d not in uniques:
         d+=1
         items.update({'id':items.get('id')+d})
         break
```

Comment: Why do you think that you went wrong in your loop?

Comment: `items.get('id') in uniques` is superfluous, of course `items.get('id')` is in `uniques`, that's how you created `uniques`.

Comment: You need to add the incremented ID to `uniques`, so you don't reuse the same incremented ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need to add the new ID to `uniques`
- You should initialize `uniques` to an empty set, otherwise you'll find a match for the first instance of each ID and increment it unnecessarily.
- You should restart `d` at `0` for each ID.
- `else: continue` is unnecessary. Loops continue automatically unless you break out of them. `continue` is generally only needed if you want to go to the next iteration from the middle of the loop body.

```
aID = copy.deepcopy(ids)
uniques = set()

for item in aID:
    d = 0
    while item['id'] + d in uniques:
        d += 1
    item['id'] += d
    uniques.add(item['id'])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250460/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-create-a-unique-id-from-each-id-in-a-list-of-dict).